# Filter truecaller spam contacts (saved with name "Identified as Spam") while importing contacts from phonebook on ios

Tags: ios, import, addressbook, spam-prevention

As per the behaviour of [truecaller](http://www.truecaller.com/) on iOS, it creates a contact named "Identified as spam" for its list of spam contacts.

While importing contacts in my app, I want to avoid importing this contact.

Is there any(localization safe) way to do it on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**kABPersonNoteProperty** property value on contact created by Truecaller always remains the same irrespective of localization. Its value is always equal to **dont_remove_this_truecaller_id**.

So, you can filter the contacts comparing this property value.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to detect them in that case. Truecaller has specifically kept it for developer use only.

Comment: But the only problem is that can be modified by user. And alternative option would be checking each number starts with 00?